# Inserting data from *.txt file into assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value

I have a text file `'test.txt'` having  fruitnames and their scientific names in separate lines.

I want to create an array as

```
$FRUIT_NAME ( fruit1=>"apple, 
              SNfruit1=>"Pyrus malus",  
              fruit2=>"mango", 
              SNfruit2=>"Mangifera indica"  ...  )
```

But, I am getting blank values in `SNfruit1`, `SNfruit2`..

Here is the `'test.txt'`

```
SNapple="Pyrus malus" 
SNmango="Mangifera indica" 
SNbanana="Musa paradisicum" 
SNorange="Citrus aurantium" 
SNDefault="No SN" 
fruit1="apple|$SNapple" 
fruit2="mango|$SNmango" 
fruit3="banana|$SNbanana" 
fruit4="orange|$SNorange" 
veg1="potato" 
veg2="cauliflower"
```

Here is the code file `'test.php'`:

```
$lines=explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));

$FRUIT_NAME=[] ;
$result=[];
for($i=0; $i<count($lines); $i++)
{   if (strpos($lines[$i], '=') !== false) 
    {  
        $link = explode('=', $lines[$i], 2); 
        if (strpos(substr($lines[$i], 0, 2), 'SN') !== false)
           $result[str_replace('"',"",$link[0])] = $link[1];
        else
        {   $FName=$link[1];
           if (strpos($link[1], '|') !== false)
              {  
                $LINK = explode('|$', $link[1]); 
                $FName=$LINK[0];
                $SN=str_replace('"',"",$LINK[1]);
              }
           else $SN="SNDefault" ;

           $FRUIT_NAME[$link[0]] = $FName ;
           //$FRUIT_NAME["SN".$link[0]] = $SN ;
           $FRUIT_NAME['SN'.$link[0]] = $result[$SN] ;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) echo "$key::$value".'<br>';

echo '============================================';

foreach ($FRUIT_NAME as $key => $value) echo "$key::$value".'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write your middle `if-else` statement:

```
if (strpos(substr($lines[$i], 0, 2), 'SN') !== false)
    $result[str_replace('"',"",$link[0])] = $link[1];
else
```

with

```
if (strpos(substr($lines[$i], 0, 2), 'SN') !== false){ 
   $result[$link[0]] = str_replace('"',"",$link[1]);
}
```

---

and

```
$FName=$link[1];
if (strpos($link[1], '|') !== false) {  
    $LINK = explode('|$', $link[1]); 
    $FName=$LINK[0];
    $SN=str_replace('"',"",$LINK[1]);
} else $SN="SNDefault" ;

$FRUIT_NAME[$link[0]] = $FName ; 
$FRUIT_NAME['SN'.$link[0]] = $result[$SN] ;
```

with

```
$link[1] = str_replace('"','',$link[1]);

if (strpos($link[1], '|$') !== false) {  
     $sublink = explode('|$', $link[1]); 
     $FRUIT_NAME[$link[0]] = $sublink[0]; 
     $FRUIT_NAME["SN".$link[0]] = $result[trim($sublink[1])];
} else { 
    $FRUIT_NAME[$link[0]] = $link[1] ; 
}
```

---

then outputs will be:

```
SNapple::Pyrus malus
SNmango::Mangifera indica
SNbanana::Musa paradisicum
SNorange::Citrus aurantium
SNDefault::No SN
============================================
fruit1::apple
SNfruit1::Pyrus malus
fruit2::mango
SNfruit2::Mangifera indica
fruit3::banana
SNfruit3::Musa paradisicum
fruit4::orange
SNfruit4::Citrus aurantium
veg1::potato
veg2::cauliflower
```

The problem was in `true` and `false` parts.

In `true` you did `str_replace` of wrong element, that's why you've received values like `"apple` instead of clean `apple`.

In `false` part you didn't `trim`, that's why indexes were incorrect and so your `$FRUIT_NAME` was built not so correctly.

**Note:** `echo '============================================'.'<br>';`

Comment: Thanks. Using trim function in  `$FRUIT_NAME['SN'.$link[0]] = $result[trim($SN)] ;` worked.